# Created pdf does not display all UTF-8 characters

Tags: pdfsharp, html-renderer

I'm creating a PDF document using HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp library. Back-end receives html from front-end and creates PDF using GeneratePdf() method.

```
PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(html, PdfSharp.PageSize.A4);
```

The process works fine when standard latin characters are used in html. I've tried to pass [UTF-8 test file](https://www.w3.org/2001/06/utf-8-test/UTF-8-demo.html) as an input in front-end and some of the characters hasn't rendered properly as seen in attached image. When I've bypassed front-end by hard-coding html value the result was the same, so I assume the problem lays in library.

Is there a way to properly render those characters with this library? I especially care about math symbols such as ∮ or ℝ ⊂ ℂ.
[image: Rendered image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/59377248

Setting font-family in html element containing math symbols to "Segoe UI Symbol" allowed PdfSharp to render those symbols properly.

Character Map is an useful tool in searching for fonts that include wanted symbols.